# Missing } in mongodb insert

Tags: mongodb

[image]

I am trying to insert data but unfortunently I keep getting this error that their is a missing curly brace after the property list how can that be

```
db.students.insert([
   { "role_num":1, "first_name":"Adilf", "last_name": "Adli", "marks":97},
   { "role_num":2,first_name:"Adil, "last_name": "Adl, "marks":93},
{ "role_num":3, "first_name":"Adi", "last_name": "Ad", "marks":89},
{ "role_num":4, "first_name":"Bonde", "last_name": "Nome", "marks":78},
{ "role_num":5, "first_name":"Bin", "last_name": "Lined", "marks":67}

]);
```

above is my insert statement

Comment: something is wrong with the quotes - hard to tell where because of missing code, screenshot is evil

Comment: check key `first_name`, you don't have quotes

Comment: On the second document you are inserting, you are missing a quotation mark closing the first name "Adil and the last name "Adl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
db.students.insert([
   { "role_num":1, "first_name":"Adilf", "last_name": "Adli", "marks":97},
   { "role_num":2, "first_name":"Adil", "last_name": "Adl", "marks":93},
   { "role_num":3, "first_name":"Adi", "last_name": "Ad", "marks":89},
   { "role_num":4, "first_name":"Bonde", "last_name": "Nome", "marks":78},
   { "role_num":5, "first_name":"Bin", "last_name": "Lined", "marks":67}
]);
```